# How do I trigger the 'Add to homescreen' prompt for a PWA?

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I have a PWA setup with a manifest and service worker such that I can manually add to the homescreen on Chrome in Android if I select the 'add to homescreen' button under the menu. I also verified on the Desktop that I can add it as a webapp in Chrome.

However, it seems that the installation banner only pops up based on some heuristics that Google selects e.g. user must interact with the site for 30 seconds etc.

What I would like is a button on my homepage, such that when I trigger it, the add to homescreen banner will automatically pop up in Chrome. How do I do this?

I want something similar to the 'Install' button on this example site: http://airhorner.com, which manually triggers the banner. However, what I would like is a minimal working example that demonstrates this.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to check is with the Chrome Audit tools.
Run the Progressive Web App audit
Under Passed Audits, you should see
--- "User can be prompted to Install the Web App"

Notes I have for A2HS
Source code links there for my working example
https://ng-chicago.github.io/2018/06/18/add-2-home-screen/
There are also reference articles I used

Most of the work when testing your A2HS is constantly clearing out your browser and previous installs (Chrome desktop and mobile) to test again.

Comment: Note: Looks like the new Chrome 68 has changed the way it uses beforeinstallprompt. I'll try to update my notes in the next few days. A2HS is a moving target.